# tkinter text widget typeError

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with a typeError in tkinter. I wrote this tiny test program to illustrate my problem:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

Text(window, width=67, height=10).grid()
Text.insert(END, "test")

window.mainloop()
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

> TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'

However, I have no idea what this argument is. It is not said or used in any tutorial I see ([effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns) for example)

I'm sure there is something really simple I'm overlooking, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set your text widget to a variable, even if you had `grid` returns None so it still wouldn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
my_text = Text(window)
my_text.grid()
my_text.insert(END, "test")
window.mainloop()
```